# how to prevent image download in outlook form region?

Tags: outlook-addin

We did an outlook addin with form regions to add tracking pixel img into email message upon sending. 
What we want to make sure is to not load that same image when user goes to sent items and opens that message after sending.

Is there a way to do it through form regions or maybe some other better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading images in the HTML of the message body is controlled by the application and the behavior cannot be modified with code.  The option to automatically download embedded images is controlled in Trust Center settings, so you could toggle this on/off by editing the registry (it should be stored there, perhaps not) but changing the setting in code probably won't take effect until Outlook is restarted.  If you need to control this on a per-message basis then you are probably out of luck.